# Laravel 5.5 return a POST response to the user's browser

Tags: post, laravel-5

I would like to know, how can I send a response POST to a client Browser.
I have this simple example in my web.php, but is in GET:

```
Route::get('proof', function() {
   $request =Place::all();
  return $request;
});
```

It works fine, but if I change the Route::get to Route::post I receive an error in my client. How can i do?
thanks

Comment: What kind of error do you have?

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: the error is for this syntax: Route::post('proof', function() {
   $request =Place::all();
  return $request;
});

Comment: Do you use form with post method?

Comment: No, I should just expose the $request(it' s a json)

Comment: How do you send request to your route?

Comment: it' s all here: Route::get('proof', function() {
   $request =Place::all();
  return $request;
}); This code is in the web.php, in the folder routes

Comment: I see You don't understand. I mean Do you put your URL `domainName/proof` in browser input?

Comment: ah ok sorry. Yes I put in the url : http://localhost/project/public/proof

Comment: I this way you need understend that your browser send only `get` request. So, if you want your code works correct you should send `post` request (througth form). For example: `<form action='localhost/project/public/proof' method='POST'><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><input type='submit'></form>`

Comment: Thanks but the result is : The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again. (i'm using Postman with post request)

Comment: it is because you need send correct csrf_token. To do it with help of postman you can just disable checking this token (read documentation how to do that).

Comment: Thanks. I find another way. I use instead of web.php the api.php. And in this  I put  a route with my post parameter. I create a Request class that extends the FormRequest and in my controller I call this class request